# Verifying the existence of a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

While reading in a JSF book, the author implements a map that serves as a namespace in which he defines some JavaScript functions.

The map is implemented like this:

```
if (!com) var com = {}
if (!com.example) {
    com.example= {
       myFunction: function(data) {

      // some code here

    }
  }
}
```

I searched to understand that syntax but didn't succeed, could someone explain to me what does `!com` means ? how can we check a variable if it's not already declared?

Comment: It means 'If the variable `com` is a falsy value, return true'. Basically, the `!` is the `not` operator. If a value is '`falsy`' (`false`, `0`, `null`, `''`, `undefined`), it will turn into `true`. Otherwise, it is turned into `false`.

Comment: As a suggestion consider not reading that book.

Comment: In addition if com is undefined it will also be falsy!
So if you do var com, and not set its value it will also return true

Comment: the shown code is a terrible pattern that doesn't work well for anything useful.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks for the explanation, Vohuman at that point :) ?

Comment: thanks everyone, I understand :) @dandavis I am not the developer of that code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (!com)` checks to see if `com` is a `falsey` value.  `if (com)` checks to see if it's a truthy value so you can see that the `!` reverses the test.

In your specific code example:

```
if (!com) var com = {};
```

the code is checking to see if the `com` variable is defined and initialized yet.  If it has not been initialized, it's value will be `undefined` which is a falsey value which will cause this code to then initialize it.

In Javascript, there are many `falsey` values and `undefined` is one such falsey value.  The falsey values are:

```
null
""
false
NaN
0
undefined
```

See [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) for more info on falsey/truthy.

---

One thing you have to be careful of is that `if (com)` or `if (!com)` may cause a reference error in some situations.  The safest way to test if a variable has been defined and initialized is this:

```
if (typeof com === "undefined")
```

because this will not cause an error in any circumstances.

Or, a common design pattern for namespaces is this:

```
var com = com || {};
```

This will define and initialize `com` as a namespace object if it doesn't already exist with a truthy value.

Comment: I saw that @dandavis said that the code is a RefError, what does that mean ?

Comment: see my answer, it's more subtle than just not falsey as my fiddle demonstrates, it involves hoisting and scope

Comment: @ToniLeigh - it depends upon the circumstance.  The OP didn't mention any sort of error related to that so they were probably using the code in a context that didn't cause a referenceError.  In any case, I've added more to my answer to address that issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I took 'how can we check a variable if it's not already declared?' to mean exactly that, as in, how does this actually work when we haven't actually done anything with that variable yet

Comment: @ToniLeigh - I took the question literally where they asked us to explain the particular syntax they illustrated in their question.  In any case, I've added better design patterns to my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's somewhat ambiguous I think, so I hold that hoisting and scope has relevance to this question

Comment: @jfriend00 in what kind of situations we may get the RefError? and thanks for the the instructive discussion between you and Toni Leigh

Comment: @Tarik - when `com` is not yet defined at all, `if (com)` will generate a reference error so `if (com)` only works when it has been defined, but not yet initialized.  If there's a `var com` ANYWHERE in scope, then Javascript's hoisting will make the variable be defined in that scope so `if (com) var com = {};` will work.  Personally, I prefer `var com = com || {};` because it handles everything for you in one simple statement.

Comment: @jfriend00 Perfect, one last question: the `var com = com || {};` also do the same thing as that code? I mean it creates a  map that serves as a namespace ?

Comment: `var com = com || {};` works? and does something you want? i would think that would leave `com=={}` no matter what... unless you locally declared it above, but in that case, why check it later?

Comment: @Tarik - yes  `var com = com || {};` makes sure that `com` either already exists and is initialized or it creates it and initializes it to an empty object.  This is a very common design pattern for declaring a namespace object that is used by many different pieces of code.  It does the same thing as `if (com) var com = {};`, but without confusion about hoisting and without putting `var` statements inside an `if()` which some people don't like to see.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3pb68zu8/

Answer (score 3):

The answer here is subtler than just checking !truthy, as the OP has acknowledged by asking why we can check a value that is not assigned. Yes, the author of the example is checking whether `com` is falsey and if so then assigning an empty object to it, but also the fact this works depends on the use of javascript [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) and [the way it is scoped](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

Javascript will look for all variables in it's current scope at the start of that scope and put memory aside for them, even if the value cannot be deduced. Because `com` is defined in the code it's initialisation is hoisted to the top of the scope it's in (global in this case) and it's already been assigned the falsey value `undefined` before the check is made.

In the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y4f9vr8x/) we can see that hoisting defines the `com` variable, but when execution gets to the next example where the var in the conditional is different from the tested variable - `if (!comA) var comB = {}` - an exception is thrown in the console.

Once assigned as an object, trying to access an undefined property on that object will also return a falsey `undefined` value and the next if block will also execute. Object properties are not treated like variables.

Answer (score 2):

The first `if` will execute when `com` is a `falsy` value. That means `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `""` or maybe `null`.

Note that

```
null == false          // returns false
```

But

```
!null == !false       // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined a variable, trying to access it will return `undefined`. Since `undefined` is falsy in JS, `!undefined` evaluates to `true`

Comment: Whoops, slip of the finger. Meant to say defined, hence the undefined

Comment: yeah, in a world of hoisting it's a crucial distinction, otherwise i'd let it slide...